# Python Tkinter and NetworkX freezes after moving mainloop to own Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, graph

I'm making a simple window to hold my NetworkX graph, and I want this GUI component to be separate from my logic. So what I'm trying to achieve is to make a function that makes the window, initializes the graph, starts the mainloop in a Thread and returns the gui reference. I've done this exact thing without  networkX and canvas involved, and it works great, but now this doesn't work for some reason. What I have is:

```
def getNewGraphWindow():
    root = Tk()
    app = GraphUI(root)

    root.mainloop()
    #mainThread = Thread(target=root.mainloop)
    #mainThread.start()
    return app
```

So this code works perfectly, it creates the window, draws the graph and all that, but obviously I don't get the "app" reference cause its stuck in the mainloop. But if I replace that code with the 2 commented out lines, to simply run root.mainloop() in its own thread, all the code runs, but the window doesn't respond and the graph is not drawn. What's wrong?

Comment: I've always encountered problems running Tk outside of the main thread. What I normally do is run Tk in the main thread and everything else in another thread.

Answer (score 2):

You have to run the mainloop in the thread where you created the `Tcl` interpreter, according to the [`_tkinter` source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/05e8f92b58ff/Modules/_tkinter.c#l142):

> The Tcl interpreter is only valid in the thread that created it, and
>   all Tk activity must happen in this thread, also. That means that the
>   mainloop must be invoked in the thread that created the interpreter.

So you'll need to run the `mainloop` in the main thread, and do whatever else you need to do in a background thread. You actually might be able to run the `mainloop` in a background thread, as long as you also create the `Tk` element in that same thread.

Comment: So I tried to change it towards this, this is my entire code right now: http://pastebin.com/TJ4mbqts

Basically I've crate the TK window and run the main loop in same Thread right now. I pass a list into that function so that I can have a pointer for the GUI. But then I get this error message: http://pastebin.com/pUH1FrRs